# moving a folder using Java or DOS move command

Tags: java, performance, file, directory, dos

Which is more efficient performance wise?

Using Java:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveDirectory(srcDir, destDir);
```

Or DOS move command:

```
mkdir destDirPath
move srcDirPath/* destDirPath
```

- Note - this code is going to be run on Windows always. Folder size is huge (around 500gb) and moving to remote system.

With my testing I found that DOS command was significantly faster but I would like to confirm if that assessment is *always* correct and also why so? Any other considerations/parameters may affect it?

Comment: Cann you tell us more about your test setup? (e.g. how did you measure the time? How did you invoke the java application)

Comment: I am running both approaches/code using Java program, measuring time taken using usual way by 'end time - start time'. As mentioned folder size is huge and moving to remote system so time taken in both approaches is in hours.

Comment: When does your `start time` start? At invocation of the jar application or right before the copy code line?

Comment: start time starts just before move code.

Comment: Actually as mentioned time taken is in hours so not very fussy about few seconds (or even minutes) here or there.

Comment: did you try with java.nio.file.Files move? it's new feature of java 7 and it may be faster than FileUtils